# cannot use FFileHelper in UE4

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I want to export String to a txt file using https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wemG-YI2iag. However, after I created the C++ class, there is no `#inlcude "ReadWriteTextFile.h"` and I cannot use FFileHelper.

It shows `cannot open source file "ReadWriteTextFile.h"` when I include it by myself. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

ReadWriteTextFile is the name of the project in the video. If your project name is "TextWriterDemo", then you must include "TextWriterDemo.h" instead.

You should be able to access and use the FFileHelper class from everywhere without including another header file since it is in the engine's Core namespace.